# How to create JuMP variables constrained on creation?

Tags: variables, constraints, julia-jump

I'm working with large multidimensional arrays in Julia in a loop framework, this means that at every instant of time I will have a large multi-dimensional Array (used to save the hystory) updating. In order to not create too many variables at each step I would like to create a specific JuMP variable in the optimization environment only if this actually exist. In other words, I want to generate a JuMP variable depending on if that value is contained in a matrix at that time instant, otherwise I don't want to create that variable.
In this silly example I want to create the a variable only for the values of S that actually exist:

julia> S = [1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0; 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
2×10 Matrix{Int64}:
1  2  3  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

julia> @variable(mdl, a[collect(1:2), collect(1:10); a in S])

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want

```
julia> S = [1 2 3 4 0 0 0 0 0 0; 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

julia> model = Model();

julia> @variable(model, a[i=1:2, j=1:10; S[i, j] > 0])
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef, 2, Tuple{Int64, Int64}} with 6 entries:
  [1, 1]  =  a[1,1]
  [1, 2]  =  a[1,2]
  [1, 3]  =  a[1,3]
  [1, 4]  =  a[1,4]
  [2, 1]  =  a[2,1]
  [2, 2]  =  a[2,2]

julia> a[1, 1]
a[1,1]

julia> a[2, 3]
ERROR: KeyError: key (2, 3) not found
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex(h::Dict{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, VariableRef}, key::Tuple{Int64, Int64})
   @ Base ./dict.jl:482
 [2] getindex(::JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{VariableRef, 2, Tuple{Int64, Int64}}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
   @ JuMP.Containers ~/.julia/packages/JuMP/Y4piv/src/Containers/SparseAxisArray.jl:130
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[17]:1
```

Documentation:

- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/getting_started/getting_started_with_JuMP/#SparseAxisArrays
- https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/variables/#variable_sparseaxisarrays